# Multi-line define in GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to make sense out of the multi-line `define` directive of GNU make and I cannot. Example:

```
define A
1
2
endef
all:
    @echo W=$(word 1,$(A))
```

Running `make` produces a result I have expected the least:

```
W=1
make: 2: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

It appears that part of `$(A)` has spilled outside the `$(word)` function.

Is it a bug or intended behavior? If the "spill" is intentional, how does it really works?

P.S. GNU make v3.81 on Linux/x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(word)` function is splitting on spaces. Not whitespace, spaces.

There are no spaces in your `A` macro so nothing gets split.

Add a trailing space on the `1` line or a leading space on the `2` line and you get your expected behaviour.

This is consistent across GNU make 3.81, 3.82, 4.0, and 4.1 in some quick testing here.

The reason you see the "spill" as you called it is because of how the define is expanded. It is expanded literally, newline and all. (Think template expansion.)

So make expands the define into the call to `$(word 1,...)` then expands that result (the whole define including the newline) into the recipe template and ends up with two lines that it executes as the recipe.

Consider a macro like this:

```
define somecommands
echo foo
echo bar
echo baz
endef

all:
    $(somecommands)
```

What would you expect to happen here? How many lines is the body of `all`? How many shells are run here? What commands are executed? The answer is three lines, three shells and three echo commands.

If the newlines weren't counted then you would effectively run `echo foo echo bar echo baz` in one command and get `foo echo bar echo baz` as output instead of the expected (and far more useful) `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` on three different lines.

Comment: I'm not asking about `$(word)` function. I'm asking for the explanation of the `make: 2: Command not found` error message. I'm interested in how/why the "2" appeared outside the function and got into the make's execution pipeline. That is the question I have asked.

Comment: You asked about how "part of `$(A)` has spilled outside the $(word) function". I just answered that question... though I see now how the answer isn't fully explained in what I wrote (though it is there). Hold on.

Comment: No. That's not really an answer. That is basically extrapolation of the official (vague on subject) documentation which doesn't address the ambiguity at all. I'm starting to think that it is simply a bug in the implementation of the multiline defines. For example, try adding a semicolon at the end of the `echo` command and see how the error message changes. (If under Linux, run with `strace -ff -e execve` to see the nonsense in all its glory.)

Comment: The semicolon changes the error because it forces make to execute a shell (make avoids that when it thinks it can). So the error changes from `exec` screaming about `2` not being a command to your shell (`/bin/sh`) screaming that `2` is not a command.

Comment: And yes, it is an answer. The value of `A` does *not* "spill" out of the call to `$(word)`. The call to `$(word)` returns the whole value of `A` unmodified. make then splats the entire definition into the recipe template (newlines included) and then splits the template into lines and runs the individual commands.

Comment: I fail to see what, in the strace output, you think is "nonsense". It makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: From `strace` output, with or without semicolon, `make` doesn't start the shell for the `echo`, because it find `/bin/echo` on the system first. Anyway, thanks for you attempt to help. It is really appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I think make "knows" about `echo` and special cases it if that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you think hasn't been explained here though.

Comment: OK, I finally managed to understand why you said what you have said. Accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The thing to remember here is that *make* stores each recipe as a single recursive variable. At the point that *make* decides that it must run your recipe, it expands that variable. *Make* then passes *each* line in the resulting expansion to a separate shell, stopping if any of those shell executions return an error.

In your example, before running anything *make* expands `@echo W=$(word 1,$(A))`.

1. `$(A)` becomes `1¶2` (dunno what this looks like on your browser, but I'm using `¶` to represent a newline character)
2. Now, `1¶2` is a single word as far as *make* is concerned, so `$(word 1,1¶2)` naturally expands to `1¶2` (can you see where this is going yet?)
3. This leaves *make* with the string `@echo W=1¶2`. Make dutifully passes the first line of this to the shell (without the `@` as that is special to *make*). The shell executes `echo W=1`.
4. *make* executes `2` in a *new* shell.
5. The second shell complains that it can't find the command `2`.

So, yes, expected behaviour.

[Warning: slight simplification in the above where I gloss over the bit where *make* is able to elide the shell and invoke the command itself if the string has no shell metacharacters in it]